# Prove $(1-\cos2\theta)/(1-\cos\theta)=2\cos\theta-2$

Tags: trigonometry

prove: $$\frac{1-\cos 2\theta}{1-\cos\theta}=2\cos\theta-2$$

I'm thinking that there will be something to square in this? Because I notice that the $LHS$ looks like the half-angle identity....

Edit: I am so sorry guys, my grave mistake, the expression should have been equal to 2 instead like,

$$\frac{1-\cos 2\theta}{1-\cos\theta}-2\cos\theta=2$$

BUT THANKS A LOT!

Comment: Hint: write $\cos(2\theta)$ in terms of $\cos(\theta)$ and then simplify the fraction.

Comment: When $\theta=\pi/2$, the left side is $2/1$, the right side is $-2$, so evidently you have not asked what you meant to ask.

Comment: is that their 'actual values'? is that acceptable to do during test exams?

Comment: @gerry i didnt get you at first but you were right! thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have, using $\cos 2\theta = 2\cos^2 \theta - 1$ $$\frac{1 - (2\cos^2 \theta -1)}{1-\cos \theta} = \frac{2(1-\cos^2 \theta)}{1-\cos \theta} = \frac{2(1-\cos \theta)(1+\cos \theta)}{1-\cos \theta} = 2(1 + \cos \theta)$$

Since $1 - \cos^2 \theta$ is a difference of two squares. The result you asked for in your question is wrong. This is the correct result. So, we have $$\bbox[10px, border: solid 2px red]{\frac{1-\cos^2 2\theta}{1-\cos \theta} = 2 \cos \theta + 2.}$$

As you can see, the above is equivalent to $$\frac{1-\cos^2 2\theta}{1-\cos \theta} - 2\cos \theta =2.$$ So the same proof works!

Comment: so my teacher's given problem has an error? is that it? thanks!

Comment: A tiny typo, that is all. Yes, the negative sign should be a plus instead. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Use the property: 
$$\cos 2 \theta=2 \cos^2 \theta-1$$

Comment: would this be the LHS after? 2cos^2$/1-cos$ ?

Comment: Substituting $\cos 2 \theta=2 \cos^2 \theta-1$ at $$\frac{1-\cos 2 \theta}{1-\cos \theta}$$ what do we get? @John

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{(1-(cos^{2}(\theta)-sin^2(\theta))}{(1-cos(\theta)}=\frac{1-cos(2\theta)}{(1-cos(\theta)}$$
Found By using property $cos(2\theta)=cos^{2}(\theta)-sin^{2}(\theta)$
$$\frac{2sin^{2}(\theta)}{1-cos(\theta)}=\frac{2(1-cos^{2}(\theta))}{(1-cos(\theta)}$$
Found By using the fact that $ 1- cos^{2}(\theta)=sin^{2}(\theta)$
$$\frac{2(1-cos(\theta)(1+cos(\theta))}{1-cos(\theta)}$$
Found by the property $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$
Which results in$$2(1+cos(\theta))$$
Not $2(1-\cos(\theta))$

Comment: i think you solved the problem??? idk how to word it, but I am supposed to show that one side is equal to the other right?

Comment: I edited my question to make it a little more clear